# Prove that there exists a node at a distance of diameter in network

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing

I have the following question in my assignment.

Given a network N, I have to show that there will be a node at the distance of $\Omega{(Diameter)}$ from a source node x.

My attempt :

If D is the diameter of the network, this implies that D is the maximum eccentricity or in other words maximum shortest path of the network. Then if I take any other source node x in the network, the shortest path (distance) of this node with any other node in the network will always $\leq$ D. Therefore, in case its lesser there wont exist a node at a distance of diameter from the source node but the statement says that there will always exist a node so I'm stuck now.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if every node is at distance at $\le d$ from $x$,  what can you say about the distance between any two nodes?

Comment: then the distance between any two nodes should also be $\leq d$ right because if the distance between any nodes $= d_2 > d$ then d wouldn't be the diameter in the first place

Comment: Also, could you please help me understand what exactly does this statement mean " hat there will be a node at the distance of Ω(Diameter) from a source node x"?
I'm gettting confused because of $\Omega$ term

Comment: @blacksheep369 No, you misunderstand my hint.  $d$ is not the diameter.

Comment: @blacksheep369 The meaning of $\Omega(Diameter)$ is that there are positive constants $k$ and $K$ (not depending on the network) such that there is a node at distance between $k \cdot Diameter$ and $K \cdot Diameter$ from $x$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Consider network A - B - C - D - E. Let x= B. then every node is at a distance $\leq$ 3. This might be silly but I'm still not sure what does this tell me about distance between any two nodes ? it can be both $> 3$ (A -D) and $< 3$ (C -D)

Comment: Yes, but no more than $6$.